# Replacing Uuid with Custom Counter Function in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having an issue where I want the string to be displayed on ListTile onPressed. Here I have a function that adds an item to the 'cart' screen with a random Uuid string, so each ListTile is unique and it works fine, but displays an ugly string on there as the picture below.

```
    addCartItem(String item) {
    
    item = item + " " + Uuid().v4();
    _cartItems.add(item);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Here is a function that adds the String of that item to the ListView as a list tile, as I mentioned the Uuid is there so each item is unique.

```
onPressed: () =>
    model.addCartItem(                                                 
          "${food.name}),
```

Here is how the added item looks, notice the ugly Uuid string, but it's necessary because each item has to be unique, otherwise I get duplicate strings error, because I want to add the same item to the ListTile, and want it to be displayed like below twice or however many times I click the button function above.

[image]

**the issue**

What I want is to get rid of ugly Uuid, and I tried doing it with a custom counter function where instead of Uuid, on each click, there would be an increment added to the string +1 for that same item, as below:

```
  add(number) {
    number++;
    return number;
  }


  addCartItem(String item) {
    
    item = item + " " + add(0).toString();
    _cartItems.add(item);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

The issue is that for some reason this is not working, what I would like is instead of the Uuid string as in the image, it just be a number that would increment how ever many times it was clicked, so 1, 1+1, 2+1 etc like in the function I made. It isn't working and is giving me the Duplicate Strings error. I would like to keep the code same, without changing it to accept anything other than a string like this.

**Why does Uuid work and the number function doesn't, it should work just as well, since the string is technically not the same, it has 1 different number.**

**error I get**
[image]

Comment: You're still winding up with equal strings because you're passing 0 to `add` every time.

Comment: It's the same if I add '1' instead of '0', I'm not sure what is it that I'm doing wrong there.

Comment: Do you have an instance variable named `number` in the class?

Comment: I have tried many ways to fix it, for such a seemingly simple issue, here is the post that explains it more in depth: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65112068/duplicate-keys-error-in-flutter-list-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I have just 'fixed' it now, by adding .substring method to the ListTile in 'cart' directly. It isn't the most elegant solution, but it works.

It just removes the Uuid code (36 letters and numbers) from view:

```
title: Text(e.substring(0, e.length - 36),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var number = 0;

addCartItem(String item) {
  item = item + " " + add(++number).toString();
  _cartItems.add(item);
  notifyListeners();
}
```

Comment: If you are looking for only multiples of each item type to increment the number for that item type, you will have to provide a pretty robust solution, keeping track of each number in a variable, or checking to see if there is a name collision each time, and then incrementing a number that inside the `addCartItem` method.

Comment: Hmm, I have been having an issue with this, for seemingly a simple problem. I added the error I get with this in the main code, I posted a picture.

Comment: Basically what I want is for number to increment each time the button is pushed, so the strings are not the same, with just the number changed, so I don't get 'duplicate strings' error.